# Sdk version fixing

Tags: android, gradle, sdk

I want to add firebase to my project,but i don't know why i got an error in this line:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-beta1'
```

how to fix that?Thanks in advance.

this is the gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.asus.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-beta1'

    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sdk versions are `v23` and support library is `v24`. Should not do that. Use a support library in the `v23` range

Comment: i have already upgraded my sdk to the latest version (25)  but i don't know why when i create a new project i always got version 23